# Invisible citations

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Is there a simple way to make citations created by `\cite{ref1}` invisible in the final manuscript (so that you can produce one version with the citations and a separate one without them)?

Comment: When reading your title, I would suggest use `\nocite{ref1}`? This makes the entries appear in the bibliography only but not in the text. I suppose this was nevertheless not what you were aiming for. Otherwise I would have replaced `\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\nocite{#1}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put

```
 \renewcommand\cite[2][]{}
```

in your preamble which will do what you ask but would make

```
blah blah \cite{ref1}.
```

make

> blah blah .

So perhaps

```
\renewcommand\cite[2][]{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}
```

Which will remove that case.

But if you have

```
blah blah blah see page 4 of \cite{ref}.
```

Then the problem is harder and you need to add extra markup such as

```
  blah blah blah\citetext{ see page 4 of \cite{ref}}.
```

where you have

```
\newcommand\citetext[1]{#1}
```

or

```
\newcommand\citetext[1]{}
```

depending.